# I an trying to disable and enable checkbox based on value in angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

Here is my code

I am having List Array like: this is getCall.
ktsessions =
[ {"presenter":"Bharath","topic":"Angular","status":"scheduled","emailId":"bharathkumar@gmail.com"}, {"presenter":"Sayyad","topic":"Angular","status":"organized","emailId":"raheemsayyad@gmail.com"},{"presenter":"Kanchan","topic":"APS","status":"scheduled","emailId":"kanchanubey@gmail.com"} ];

```
<tr *ngFor = "let ktsession of ktsessions >

  <td ><input type="checkbox" [disabled]='disabled'></td>
</tr>
```

TS code:

```
getktsession(){   
    this.service.getKtsession().subscribe(data =>{
      console.log('get', data);
      this.ktsessions = data;
      this.ktsessions.find(user => {
     
       if(user.presenter ==="Kanchan"){
       this.disabled = true
} else {
this.disabled = false;
}
        
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.

1. `<tr *ngFor = "let ktsession of ktsessions >` - Missing closing quote after `ktsessions`
2. `<td ><input type="checkbox" [disabled]='disabled'></td>` - `[disabled]='disabled'` should be `[disabled]="ktsession.disabled"`. Each checkbox instance needs to have its own `disabled` property. `[disabled]='disabled'` sets each checkbox's `disabled` property to the `disabled` property of the component class instance rather than the checkbox instance.
3. `this.ktsessions.find(user => {` - [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is not an appropriate method to use here, even though it happens to work since you're not returning anything from the callback function and it will therefore iterate the entire array. Array#find is for searching an array for an element that matches the specified criteria and returning that element, not for iterating over an array and setting properties on each element, which is what you're doing here. [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the appropriate method for that.
4. `this.disabled = true` and `this.disabled = false` - these are setting the `disabled` property on the component class instance (which is what `this` refers to), but what you need to do is set the `disabled` property on each `user` instance: `user.disabled = true` or `user.disabled = false`.

So your template should look something like this:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let ktsession of ktsessions">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="ktsession.disabled" /> <!-- reference "ktsession.disabled" instead of "disabled" -->
    {{ ktsession.presenter }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

And your `subscribe` should look something like this:

```js
this.getKtsession().subscribe((data) => {
  this.ktsessions = data;
  this.ktsessions.forEach((user) => { // <-- use forEach, not find
    if (user.presenter === 'Kanchan') {
      user.disabled = true; // <------------ set user.disabled, not this.disabled
    } else {
      user.disabled = false; // <----------- set user.disabled, not this.disabled
    }
  });
});
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cewkjr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) showing it working with those changes.